# How to set up language input?

Tags: kubuntu, language-support, internationalization, input-language, input-method

I'm trying to set up Kubuntu 11.10 so I can type Japanese. I've searched online but have had little luck. My installation is fresh so it'd be great if someone could walk me through it and tell me how to do it from the beginning.